# Shell Scripting to pass a command and display its output

Tags: shell

I want to pass a command and get the answer printed.
I have tried this

```
#!/bin/sh
cmd = `ps -ef|grep processname`
echo "$cmd"
```

But i am getting the error as

```
: command not found 4: cmd
```

the output of this command may be 5 or 6 lines.
I just want to view them.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra spaces you have either side of the equals symbol.

```
cmd=`ps -ef|grep processname`
```

Comment: what if $cmd does not give an output.How to write a condition. If $cmd gives an output and what if it does not

Answer (score 0):

try switching to bash, rather than sh

```
cmd="$(ps -ef|grep apache)"
echo "$cmd"
```

yields

```
bob@cindy:~$ echo "$cmd"
root      1914     1  0 Sep08 ?        00:01:37 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1990     1  0 Sep08 ?        00:01:09 /usr/bin/htcacheclean -d 120 -p /var/cache/apache2/mod_cache_disk -l 300M -n
bob 13511 13509  0 08:18 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache
www-data 29841  1914  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29842  1914  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29843  1914  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29844  1914  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 29845  1914  0 00:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: what if $cmd does not give an output.How to write a condition. If $cmd gives an output and what if it does not.